# NPM download for offline installation

Tags: docker, npm

I'm looking for a way to download all the NPM sources mentioned in one or more package-lock.json files while online, and to be able to feed these to a NPM install without network connectivity.

The end goal is to allow a Docker buildfile which uses 'npm install' to run without any network connectivity during the build so we can verify that the build is repeatable and does not rely on a npm package which might go away in the future. These builds would be helpful to prove completeness for escrow purposes.

So I can't rely on NPMs automatic caching, I probably need to control this. Ideally I could feed the downloaded packages from OSX into Docker, but if a solution only works on Linux it's fine too..

Does such a tool exist or does NPM itself provide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm works offline, the dependencies are cached locally automatically. Remember to install a latest version available.

Comment: It's the automatic caching I don't want, I need to have control over it. The dependencies need to be downloaded outside of docker, passed into it as part of the build context, and the build should be able to 'npm install' without requiring network connectivity

Comment: I like your line of thought 'try not to avoid hitting the registry, but BE the local registry'. Still didn't get a chance to give it a shot, but if I can set up a ccache-memcached server to use during builds, I surely should be able to figure out a registry server